# Addition of cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks to Ionic 4 project renders unable to build

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, cocoapods

Would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve conflict with plugins when building Ionic 4 Cordova app for IOS w xcode.

Below are my working plugins - i.e. project builds successfully with these plugins.

BUT, when trying to add [cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks) using:

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks --variable APP_DOMAIN="example.ca" --variable PAGE_LINK_DOMAIN="example.page.link";
```

addition fails with error:

```
    Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 31
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/name/project/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
pod: Command failed with exit code 31
```

As discovered through search, I have tried:

platforms/ios/pod repo update
platforms/ios/pod install

which execute successfully prior to addition of cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks

MY WORKING SET OF PLUGINS (these build w/ success prior to addition of dynamiclinks plugin):

```
cordova-plugin-androidx 1.0.2 "cordova-plugin-androidx"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.0 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-firebasex 7.0.1 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-google-analytics 1.8.6 "Google Universal Analytics Plugin"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 8.2.1 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"
cordova-sqlite-storage 3.4.1 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
cordova-support-google-services 1.3.2 "cordova-support-google-services"
```

IONIC INFO:

Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.15 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.8
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.800.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.2.2
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 14 other plugins)

Utility:

cordova-res                          : 0.8.1
   native-run (update available: 0.3.0) : 0.2.8

System:

ios-sim : 8.0.2
   NodeJS  : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm     : 6.13.6
   OS      : macOS Mojave
   Xcode   : Xcode 11.3.1 Build version 11C504

Comment: There is no ionic in front of your command. Should start with "ionic cordova plugin add ..."

Answer (score 3):

`cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks` conflict with `cordova-plugin-firebasex`.

so you need to sync `Firebase Dependency`

look Podfile example

```
    pod 'Firebase/Core', '6.17.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth', '6.17.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '6.17.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Performance', '6.17.0'
    pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '6.17.0'
```

firebase version is '6.17.0'. this is because of `firebasex`

so you must change
`plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks/plugin.xml`

```
<pods>
    <pod name="Firebase/Analytics" spec="~> 6.17.0" />
    <pod name="Firebase/DynamicLinks" spec="~> 6.17.0" />
</pods>
```

it have to be same with firebasex's Firebase dependency.